# Aligning the long equations

Tags: formatting, amsmath

I have read all of the different solutions for fitting long formulas in a page, yet I am still not satisfied with the output I get. The formulas are right aligned which does not look good. 
Would you please let me know if you have a better solution. This is my code:

```
\begin{equation}

\begin{split}
(1-\mathbf{B})\begin{bmatrix} y_1\\y_2  \\ y_3 \end{bmatrix} &= \\
(\begin{bmatrix} 1\\1  \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix} 0.30064^{*} & -0.70171 &-10.27380 \\ 0.00206 &  0.35560^{*} &  -0.62373 \\  0.00013 & 0.00228 &  0.77829^{*} \end{bmatrix}\mathbf{B}-\\
\begin{bmatrix} -0.24890^{*} &  0.53801 &  -3.03724 \\  -0.00600 &   0.20570^{*} &  -1.04583 \\ -0.00010 & -0.00189 &  0.27768^{*}  \end{bmatrix}\mathbf{B}^2-\\
\begin{bmatrix} 0.61824^{*} &  0.33973 & -1.09651 \\  -0.00287 &   -0.12782 & 2.79815 \\  -0.00002 & -0.00249 &  -0.07773 \end{bmatrix}\mathbf{B}^3) \begin{bmatrix} \varepsilon_{1t} \\ \varepsilon_{2t} \\ \varepsilon_{3t}  \end{bmatrix}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.sx, it's helpful (for future questions) to always include complete documents showing all packages used (as in my answer) rather than fragments.

Answer (score 12):

Long equations like this can sometimes hide the important details- I would consider using local definitions, such as

[image: screenshot]

Here's a complete MWE

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: true}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Consider the equation
\begin{equation}
    (1-\mathbf{B})\vec{y} = (1-M_1-M_2\mathbf{B}^2-M_3\mathbf{B}^3)\vec{\epsilon}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{align*}
    M_1 & = \begin{bmatrix} 0.30064^{*}  & -0.70171 & -10.27380 \\ 0.00206 &  0.35560^{*} &  -0.62373 \\  0.00013 & 0.00228 &  0.77829^{*} \end{bmatrix}\\
    M_2 & = \begin{bmatrix} -0.24890^{*} & 0.53801  & -3.03724  \\  -0.00600 &   0.20570^{*} &  -1.04583 \\ -0.00010 & -0.00189 &  0.27768^{*}  \end{bmatrix}\\
    M_3 & = \begin{bmatrix} 0.61824^{*}   & 0.33973  & -1.09651  \\  -0.00287 &   -0.12782 & 2.79815 \\  -0.00002 & -0.00249 &  -0.07773 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Further enhancements can be made using the [`siunitx`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/siunitx/siunitx.pdf) package to help with decimal alignment.

[image: siunitx]

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: on, localSettings: true}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

Consider the equation
\begin{equation}
    (1-\mathbf{B})\vec{y} = (1-M_1\mathbf{B}-M_2\mathbf{B}^2-M_3\mathbf{B}^3)\vec{\epsilon}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{align*}
    M_1 & = 
    \left[
        \setlength{\arraycolsep}{10pt}
        \begin{array}{S[table-format=1.5] S[table-format=1.5] S[table-format=2.5]}
            0.30064$^*$ & -0.70171    & -10.27380   \\ 
            0.00206     & 0.35560$^*$ & -0.62373    \\  
            0.00013     & 0.00228     & 0.77829$^*$ 
        \end{array}
    \right]
    \\
    M_2 & = 
    \left[
        \setlength{\arraycolsep}{10pt}
        \begin{array}{S[table-format=1.5] S[table-format=1.5] S[table-format=1.5]}
            -0.24890$^{*}$ & 0.53801       & -3.03724      \\  
            -0.00600       & 0.20570$^{*}$ & -1.04583      \\ 
            -0.00010       & -0.00189      & 0.27768$^{*}$ 
        \end{array}
    \right]
    \\
    M_3 & = 
    \left[
        \setlength{\arraycolsep}{10pt}
        \begin{array}{S[table-format=1.5] S[table-format=1.5] S[table-format=1.5]}
            0.61824$^{*}$ & 0.33973  & -1.09651 \\  
            -0.00287      & -0.12782 & 2.79815  \\  
            -0.00002      & -0.00249 & -0.07773 
        \end{array}
    \right]
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd give +2, one for each half of your answer.  Though I think the columns are a little tight in your second example.

Comment: agreed about good answer ans advice, but it still looks a little raggedy.  alignment on the decimal points would improve the appearance greatly.

Comment: @cmhughes -- i see it now -- nice.  (i could have sworn it wasn't that nicely aligned with i first looked at it though.)

Answer (score 5):

I'd structure the three lines so that the large matrices are aligned vertically. I'd also decimal-align the numbers in the three 3x3 matrices. To that effect, you could use the `dcolumn` package; this requires using `array` environments rather than `pmatrix` environments. You can still use the `pmatrix` environment for the three column vectors, of course.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand\arraycolsep{3pt} % default value: 6pt
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\begin{split} \label{eq:threelign}
(1-\mathbf{B})
\begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\y_2  \\ y_3 \end{bmatrix}
=  \left(
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\1  \\ 1 \\ \end{bmatrix} 
\right.
&- \left[ \begin{array}{d{2.5}d{3.5}d{3.5}} 
0.30064^{*} & -0.70171 &-10.27380 \\ 
0.00206 &  0.35560^{*} &  -0.62373 \\  
0.00013 & 0.00228 &  0.77829^{*} \\
\end{array}\right] \mathbf{B} \\
&- \left[ \begin{array}{d{2.5}d{3.5}d{3.5}} 
-0.24890^{*} &  0.53801 &  -3.03724 \\  
-0.00600 &   0.20570^{*} &  -1.04583 \\ 
-0.00010 & -0.00189 &  0.27768^{*} \\ 
\end{array}\right] \mathbf{B}^2  \\
&- \left.
   \left[ \begin{array}{d{2.5}d{3.5}d{3.5}} 
0.61824^{*} &  0.33973 & -1.09651 \\  
-0.00287 &   -0.12782 & 2.79815 \\  
-0.00002 & -0.00249 &  -0.07773 
\end{array}\right] \mathbf{B}^3
\right) 
\begin{bmatrix} 
\varepsilon_{1t} \\ \varepsilon_{2t} \\ \varepsilon_{3t}  
\end{bmatrix}
\end{split}\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's another possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
(1-\mathbf{B})
\begin{bmatrix} y_1\\y_2  \\ y_3 \end{bmatrix} 
&= 
\left(\begin{bmatrix} 1\\1  \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
- \begin{bmatrix} 0.30064^{*} & -0.70171 & -10.27380 \\ 0.00206 &  0.35560^{*} &  -0.62373 \\  0.00013 & 0.00228 &  0.77829^{*} \end{bmatrix}\mathbf{B}\right. \\
&\qquad{} - \begin{bmatrix} -0.24890^{*} &  0.53801 &  -3.03724 \\  -0.00600 &   0.20570^{*} &  -1.04583 \\ -0.00010 & -0.00189 &  0.27768^{*}  \end{bmatrix}\mathbf{B}^2\\
&\qquad{} - \left.\begin{bmatrix} 0.61824^{*} &  0.33973 & -1.09651 \\  -0.00287 &   -0.12782 & 2.79815 \\  -0.00002 & -0.00249 &  -0.07773 \end{bmatrix}\mathbf{B}^3\right) \begin{bmatrix} \varepsilon_{1t} \\ \varepsilon_{2t} \\ \varepsilon_{3t}  \end{bmatrix}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice the use of pairs `\left...\right` to get the big delimiters, and also of `{} - ...` so that the minus signs at the beginning of lines get treated as binary operators.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps `multline` here as there is not really any alignment point:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

original equation/split
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
(1-\mathbf{B})\begin{bmatrix} y_1\\y_2  \\ y_3 \end{bmatrix} &= \\
(\begin{bmatrix} 1\\1  \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix} 0.30064^{*} & -0.70171 &-10.27380 \\ 0.00206 &  0.35560^{*} &  -0.62373 \\  0.00013 & 0.00228 &  0.77829^{*} \end{bmatrix}\mathbf{B}-\\
\begin{bmatrix} -0.24890^{*} &  0.53801 &  -3.03724 \\  -0.00600 &   0.20570^{*} &  -1.04583 \\ -0.00010 & -0.00189 &  0.27768^{*}  \end{bmatrix}\mathbf{B}^2-\\
\begin{bmatrix} 0.61824^{*} &  0.33973 & -1.09651 \\  -0.00287 &   -0.12782 & 2.79815 \\  -0.00002 & -0.00249 &  -0.07773 \end{bmatrix}\mathbf{B}^3) \begin{bmatrix} \varepsilon_{1t} \\ \varepsilon_{2t} \\ \varepsilon_{3t}  \end{bmatrix}
\end{split}
\end{equation}



new multline
\begin{multline}
(1-\mathbf{B})\begin{bmatrix} y_1\\y_2  \\ y_3 \end{bmatrix} = {}\\
\Biggl(\begin{bmatrix} 1\\1  \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix} 0.30064^{*} & -0.70171 &-10.27380 \\ 0.00206 &  0.35560^{*} &  -0.62373 \\  0.00013 & 0.00228 &  0.77829^{*} \end{bmatrix}\mathbf{B}-{}\\
\begin{bmatrix} -0.24890^{*} &  0.53801 &  -3.03724 \\  -0.00600 &   0.20570^{*} &  -1.04583 \\ -0.00010 & -0.00189 &  0.27768^{*}  \end{bmatrix}\mathbf{B}^2-{}\\
\begin{bmatrix} 0.61824^{*} &  0.33973 & -1.09651 \\  -0.00287 &   -0.12782 & 2.79815 \\  -0.00002 & -0.00249 &  -0.07773 \end{bmatrix}\mathbf{B}^3\Biggr)
 \begin{bmatrix} \varepsilon_{1t} \\ \varepsilon_{2t} \\ \varepsilon_{3t}  \end{bmatrix}
\end{multline}


\end{document}
```