# How to prevent white space when aligning equations/ prevent wasting paper by filling the page?

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath, overleaf

I code very often on LaTeX yet I do not have a good understanding of how to properly space my work, in math mode. Although the latter may sound very ambiguous, which it is, I am referring to something like this:

```
Find the value of
\begin{align*}
   \mathbb{L} = \int_0^1 \sum_{k\geq1}\psi^{(1)}(n)x^n\ \mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}
Solution. It is known that $\sum_{k\geq1}\psi^{(1)}(n)x^n := \frac{x}{1-x}\left(\zeta(2)-\operatorname{Li}_2(x)\right)$ which implies 
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{L} &= \int_0^1 \frac{x}{1-x}\left(\zeta(2)-\operatorname{Li}_2(x)\right)\ \mathrm{d}x, \\
      &= -\int_0^1 \left(\zeta(2)-\operatorname{Li}_2(x)\right)\ \mathrm{d}x-\int_0^1 \frac{\zeta(2)-\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{x}\ \mathrm{d}x, \\
      &\stackrel{\text{IBP}}{=} -1+\int_0^1 \frac{\log^2\left(1-x\right)}{x}\ \mathrm{d}x= 2\zeta(3)-1.
\end{align*}
```

How would I be able to place some of the equations like the second line subsequent to \mathbb{L} in the center of the page? Is there any better way to "fill a page" with math rather than to have poor alignments and waste paper? If so, how would I go about doing this? If it means anything, I use Overleaf. Thank you, in advance!

[Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108040/aligning-the-long-equations) is a some-what related question.

Comment: Do you want every line of the eqution to be centered?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1):

You asked,

> Is there any better way to "fill a page" with math rather than to have poor alignments and waste paper?

I'm not sure what you mean by filling a page (needlessly? wantonly?) with math. The following touch-ups to your code may provide for a more streamlined appearance -- as well as code that's easier to maintain and debug:

- Don't overuse `align` and `align*` environments. use them only for multiline equations. By using `\[...\]` for the first displayed equation, you actually get a more compact typeset result.
- Learn about `amsmath`'s `\DeclareMathOperator` instruction. E.g., by running `\DeclareMathOperator{\Li}{Li}` in the preamble, you can replace all subsequent instances of `\operatorname{Li}` with `\Li`.
- Don't overuse `\left` and `\right`; quite often, they do *not* achieve their intended purpose. For example, in `\left(\zeta(2)-\operatorname{Li}_2(x)\right)`, `\left` and `\right` do not manage to increase the size of the parentheses. I'd either omit them outright or replace them with `\bigl(` and `\bigr)`.
- If you write `\stackrel{\text{IBP}}{=}`, the `=` symbol will *not* be aligned with the `=` symbols in the preceding rows. I suggest you use `\stackrel{\mathclap{\textup{\tiny IBP}}}{=}` instead. (`\mathclap` is a macro that's provided by the `mathtools` package, which is a superset of the `amsmath` package.)
- Use a dedicated macro -- defined via, say, `\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}` - to typeset differential operators.
- Use `\dfrac` in the material after `Solution.` Likewise, use `\coloneqq` instead of `:=`. (The latter isn't defined automatically to have status `mathrel`.)
- Last but not least, I'd put `2\zeta(3)-1` on a line by itself. The increase in visual clarify surely outweighs the cost caused by the very slight increase in space occupied by the `align*` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb} % for \mathclap and \coloneqq macros
\DeclareMathOperator{\Li}{Li}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}} % "differential" operator

\begin{document}
\noindent
Find the value of
\[
\mathbb{L} = \int_0^1 \sum_{k\geq1} \psi^{(1)}(n) x^n\diff x.
\]
Solution. It is known that 
$\sum_{k\geq1} \psi^{(1)}(n) x^n \coloneqq 
\dfrac{x}{1-x}\bigl(\zeta(2)-\Li_2(x)\bigr)$. 
This implies 
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{L} 
      &= \int_0^1 \frac{x}{1-x}\bigl(\zeta(2)-\Li_2(x)\bigr)\diff x \\
      &= -\int_0^1 \bigl(\zeta(2)-\Li_2(x)\bigr)\diff x
         -\int_0^1 \frac{\zeta(2)-\Li_2(x)}{x}\diff x, \\
      &\stackrel{\mathclap{\textup{\tiny IBP}}}{=} 
         -1+\int_0^1 \frac{\log^2(1-x)}{x}\diff x\\
      &= 2\zeta(3)-1\,.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yeah my question was a bit vague... For \stackrel -- what would I use to have math above the equals sign? For example if I said wanted to substitute something; how would I do that without the following math being "in the way"?